# Spring WebRequest getParameter() is showing null

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, mailchimp, webhooks

I have a problem while trying to process a Mailchimp Webhook request with a Spring MVC Controller **in a hosted Tomcat server** (while in my own development environment, everything works perfectly).

I just add a "secret" parameter to the webhook URL, like this:

```
http://doamin/webhook.html?secret=password
```

Mailchimp makes a POST request to the webapp, but they say you should add a "secret" key to the URL (GET parameter therefore) for security reasons.

Then I just check that parameter before going into business logic, by...

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postProcess(WebRequest request){
    if (request.getParameter("secret").equals("password"){
        //business logic
    }
}
```

**This is ok in my own local tomcat. Parameter is correctly grabbed from the Mailchimp request, and all business logic is run.**

But then I upload my WAR to the production environment, and I can see there that the business logic is not being run.

After a lot of fun debugging... I find out that the getParameter("secret") returns me null.

Doy you think it could be something related to tomcat conf?

My local tomcat is version 7.0.67.

My hosted tomcat is version 7.0.62

My web.xml looks like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>

  <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--  Load up all spring xml files as part of the loading of the webapp -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security-config.xml;/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

     <!--  This filter is used by Spring Security to intercept all URL patterns -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/Forbidden.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
      <exception-type>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException</exception-type>
      <location>/JDBCException.html</location>
    </error-page>   

    <!-- Session expiration max time (in minutes) -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

And my hosted server.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE server-xml [
  <!ENTITY jelastic-ssl SYSTEM "jelastic-ssl.xml">
  <!ENTITY jelastic-ha SYSTEM "jelastic-ha.xml">
]>

<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />

    <!--############## SSL Connector for _domain_name ### PROTO_Dl231aIDsW4 ##########-->
    &jelastic-ssl;
    <!--############## SSL Connector for _domain_name ### PROTO_Dl541aINsMx ##########-->
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="${jvmRid}">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="${jvmRid}">

    <!--Jelastic HA clusteting is enabled here so please do not remove this line untill you reasly know what you are doing -->
    &jelastic-ha;
    <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Edited:
**More testing:**

I have commented the code where I ask for the secret key. So then, the business logic is run, of course. But within that business logic, I also ask for the POST parameters, and what a surprise!!!! I'm also getting a NullPointerException every single time I try to access my WebRequest parameters.

If I restart tomcat, the first time the code is run, it works, but then, If I repeat the call, NullPointerException arises.

My problematic code architecture is like this:

1) A threaded process to be called by the MVC controller, since I need to answer Mailchimp in less than 15 seconds, while in the background I start a thread to run the business logic:

```
package es.edm.util;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

import es.edm.services.MailingListService;

public class MailingListRequestProcessor implements Runnable {

    private Thread t;
    private WebRequest request;
    private MailingListService mailing;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(new Date() + ": Request status afet calling the thread to start, but before calling business logic" + request);
        mailing.processRequest(request);
    }

    public void start (WebRequest request, MailingListService mailing) {
        if (t == null){
            System.out.println(new Date() + ": Request status before calling the thread to start" + request);
            this.request = request;
            this.mailing = mailing;
            t = new Thread (this, "MailchimpRequest");
            t.start ();
        }
    }
}
```

2) The controller, creating the thread and answering Mailchimp request:

```
package es.edm.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import es.edm.services.MailingListService;
import es.edm.util.MailingListRequestProcessor;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/Webhook")
public class MailingServiceIntegrationController_MailchimpImpl {

    @Autowired
    MailingListService mailing;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getProcess(WebRequest request){
        return new ModelAndView("/web/MailchimpAnswer.jsp");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView postProcess(WebRequest request){
        MailingListRequestProcessor processor = new MailingListRequestProcessor();
        processor.start(request, mailing);
        return new ModelAndView("/web/MailchimpAnswer.jsp");
    }
}
```

3) And the Service class for implementing the business logic:

```
@Override
public void processRequest(WebRequest request) {
    //To recover, once solved the problem with Jelastic and getParameters();
    //if (request.getParameter("secret")!= null){
        //if (request.getParameter("secret").equals(conf.getMailingListSecretPassword())){
            switch (request.getParameter("type")){
            case "subscribe": processSubscribe(request); break;
            case "unsubscribe": processUnsubscribe(request); break;
            case "profile": processProfile(request); break;
            case "upemail": processEmailChange(request); break;
            case "cleaned": processCleanedEmail(request); break;
            case "campaign": processCampaign(request); break;
            }
        //}
    //}
}
```

The catalina output is this:

```
Exception in thread "MailchimpRequest" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.edm.services.Impl.MailingListService_Mailchimp_Impl.processRequest(MailingListService_Mailchimp_Impl.java:37)
    at es.edm.util.MailingListRequestProcessor.run(MailingListRequestProcessor.java:15)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

MailingListService_Mailchimp_Impl.java:37 is this:

```
switch (request.getParameter("type")){
```

request.getParameter("type") is null... while in my local tomcat is correctly filled in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, I end up to find the problem:

```
<!-- This should be removed to improve security!!!! -->
<csrf disabled="true"/>
```

You can not use CSRF protection while working with Mailchimp, as it needs to pass the "secret" parameter as a GET parameter, but CSRF is there to block it out.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Jelastic, try to reach Jelastic support. I guess they could help you in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Intellio. Now it is solved: It was a problem with this:

      <!-- This should be removed to improve security!!!! -->
  <csrf disabled="tr

With CSRF enabled, you can not hook Mailchimp with Spring, since it is properly catched out.

All I needed to do is disable it.